# getting failed to obtain info for control in alsa setup while booting the raspbain?

Tags: controls, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

I am getting the error or warning like  `failed to obtain info for control #335` while booting the raspbain on the raspberry pi

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Run `alsactl store`.

Comment: @CL. what is that for? why i got that error / warning?

Comment: You probably have some saved settings from an older driver version which had different mixer controls.